# Drag n' drop between two material tables

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-table

I'm trying to implement drag n' drop into my project, but are a little stumped as to how to begin. In Angular 7 we now have the cdkDragDrop, which seems very promising. However, all the examples are based on one or more lists/divs. I would like to use it with two material tables - is this even possible? Are there any other examples out there, [other than the ones at Angular Material?](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Answer (score 0):

I created a [working example at Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5bddkx) However, the actual items that are moved from array to array are not the same as the ones that are dragged. I guess it can be because the index in the arrays not necessarily are the same as the ones in the tables? Any input?

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

ELEMENT_DATA2: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},

];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
  dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA2);

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
      console.log("event.previousContainer =>", event.previousContainer);
      console.log("event.container =>", event.container)
      console.log("event.container.data =>", event.container.data)
      console.log("event.previousIndex =>", event.previousIndex);
      console.log("event.currentIndex =>", event.currentIndex);
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
    this.dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA2);
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

-

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"
  class="mat-elevation-z8" cdkDropList #table1="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="ELEMENT_DATA" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[table2]"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" cdkDrag></tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource2" class="mat-elevation-z8"
  cdkDropList #table2="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="ELEMENT_DATA2"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[table1]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" cdkDrag></tr>
</table>




<!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

-

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.example-box:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```